# Django cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects on DateField

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I'm pretty new with Mezzanine and Django. I'm getting an error when trying to save a date field off an admin form:

```
cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

models.py:

```
release_date = models.DateField("Release Date", null=True, blank=True)
```

admin.py:

```
film_fieldsets = deepcopy(DisplayableAdmin.fieldsets)
film_fieldsets[0][1]["fields"].insert(1, "release_date")
```

The date field rendered by django seems to save in the YYYY-MM-DD, i.e. 2016-02-18. I'm guessing that the dashes are causing the mismatch, but did I just not implement the field correctly or do I need to add a function to process this?

Answer (score 0):

Your field should be
models.py

```
release_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="Release Date", null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you are trying to pass the string: `"release_date"` to `film_fieldsets`

try this:

`film_fieldsets[0][1]["fields"].insert(1, release_date)`

and if the data in `release_date` throws a string to int conversion error you might trying forcing it like so

`film_fieldsets[0][1]["fields"].insert(1, str(release_date))`